# Label Multi classes in keras /Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have a training images of 10 classes in  separate folders.(namely from 0 to 9)
Am struck with labelling the data .
Should I need to follow one hot encoding for each image or each class??  Or any other method? 
So far I had hands on binary classification.

Comment: Welcome to SO; your question is way too broad, please do take some time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). That said, you may want to have a look at the [Keras MNIST example](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_cnn.py), which sounds very close to your context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mentioned you have `10` classes. You can label them in any name you want. For instance `class 1 : 'A', class '2' : 'B'` and so on.

But while training a deep learning model, you have to encode the labels. As you mentioned you are familiar with binary classification where the input labels are either `0` or `1` for `cats` and `dogs` classification, here the labels must be `0`, `1`, `2`, ..... , `9`.

For training a model, you can't use this label directly. You must one-hot encode these labels and provide it as `y` for your model. Your model must have `10` nodes in the output layer. `argmax()` on the prediction made by the model will tell you which class do the test data belong.